# Can the color of the underline below the text be changed to a different color than the text in Corel Draw x7?

Tags: text, corel-draw

I am making a visiting card in corel draw X7. I want to change the color of the underline of a word but when I do it the color of the whole text changes too. Please tell me how to change the color of underline without changing the color of text itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a new thin rectangle and put under the text you would like to underline. You can then group the 2 objects to keep together.

Too bad it isn't as easy as CSS.

Comment: So tempted to downvote you for that last sentence. I loathe CSS :P

Comment: @Ryan that's a shame, CSS is awesome! Usually it is easier to design in any design program but for this it would be so much more simple if you could just do a bottom-border character style.

Comment: Is there any direct method to select the underline and fill the color directly?

Comment: By the way what is CSS?

Comment: @JATT The method I used is using a new line (object) entirely (Not using the underline text). My method would make it easy to keep text in-tact and change the underline color. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet, it is used to format HTML.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be this:

1. Add text without underline
2. Adjust text to correct size, font, and color
3. Use the Pen tool to create a straight stroke
4. Adjust the fill of the stroke to the color desired for the underline
5. Place the new line under the text field

You now should only have to copy and paste the stroke under each word that needs it. This seems like a ton of work, but for a custom look sometimes the extra steps can pay off. Hope the best.